# parallel.for loop values into the chart

Tags: c#, for-loop

```
 public void subReadFile_Max_V(List<List<double>> list)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i <= clsGlobe.fileNum - 1; i++)
        {
            int _count = 2;
            //for (int j = _count; j < clsGlobe.Row-2; j++)
            //{
            //    if(clsGlobe._sheet._ListWorksheets[i].Cells[j, clsGlobe.max_v_posiotn].value != null)
            //    {
            //        list[i].Add(clsGlobe._sheet._ListWorksheets[i].Cells[j, clsGlobe.max_v_posiotn].value);
            //    }
            //    else
            //    {
            //        break;
            //    }
            //}
            Parallel.For(_count, clsGlobe.Row - 2, j =>
            {
                list[i].Add(clsGlobe._sheet._ListWorksheets[i].Cells[j, clsGlobe.max_v_posiotn].value);
            });
        }
    }
```

---

```
    private void cbTitle_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(clsGlobe.lmaxVoltage.lMaxVoltage[0].Count!=0 && clsGlobe.lminVoltage.lMinVoltage[0].Count!=0 && clsGlobe.lmaxTem.lMaxTem[0].Count != 0)
        {

            try
            {
                Point_Clear(clsGlobe.fileNum);
                if (clsGlobe._SOC.lSOC[0] > clsGlobe._SOC.lSOC[200])
                {
                    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsReversed = true;
                }
                switch (cbTitle.SelectedIndex)
                {
                    case 0:
                        {
                            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = 3200;
                            for (int i = 1; i <= clsGlobe.fileNum; i++)
                            {
                                for (int j = 1; j <= clsGlobe._SOC.lSOC.Count - 2; j++)
                                {
                                    chart1.Series[i - 1].Points.AddXY(clsGlobe._SOC.lSOC[j], clsGlobe.lmaxVoltage.lMaxVoltage[i - 1][j]);
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        }
```

I using parallel.for loop to put values into the list sequentially.
When I use the chart bring  the values.
the chart shows that this is problem.

I use the for loop is normal
but there is problem with using parallel.for loop

Comment: You need to provide more details. Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask (for example: "if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some" and "Include any error messages")

Comment: IMHO using `parallel.for` to get a `sequentially` read, seems counter productive, as I would assume synchronizing the `parallel` tasks to make it `sequentially` would be a bigger overhead than to simply fetch the data without parallalism

Comment: since you are saying `I use the for loop is normal but there is problem with using parallel.for loop` - how do you synchronize the data? (if at all) show your code if possible

Comment: thanks you comment, I have added the code, the annotation part is a for loop, when using annotation is no problem

Comment: there is so much wrong with using a parallel loop like this. 1) you should typically parallelize the *outer* loop. 2) adding to a list is *not thread safe*.  3) this probably do not benefit much from parallelization since there is nothing compute heavy inside the loop. 4) If you have *lots* of values you should probably think about memory layout and doing block copies rather than copying singular values.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance.I'm trying to replace the parallel.for with something else or using  for loop.thanks

Answer (score 1):

Calling `list[i].Add` will `Add` items to the list at random, when ever the parallel worker finishes its job.

```
public void subReadFile_Max_V(List<List<double>> list)
{
    for(int i = 0; i <= clsGlobe.fileNum - 1; i++)
    {
        int _count = 2;
        Parallel.For(_count, clsGlobe.Row - 2, j =>
        {
            list[i].Add(clsGlobe._sheet._ListWorksheets[i].Cells[j, clsGlobe.max_v_posiotn].value);
        });
    }
}
```

So at the very least you should consider instead of calling `Add`, to set the value at a given index. eg. `list[i][j] = {value};`

```
public void subReadFile_Max_V(List<List<double>> list)
{
    for(int i = 0; i <= clsGlobe.fileNum - 1; i++)
    {
        int _count = 2;

        //init the list, so that each index of the list is accessable
        list[i].Clear();
        for (int x = 0; x < clsGlobe.Row - 2; x++)
            list.Add(0);

        Parallel.For(_count, clsGlobe.Row - 2, j =>
        {
            list[i][j] = clsGlobe._sheet._ListWorksheets[i].Cells[j, clsGlobe.max_v_posiotn].value;
        });
    }
}
```

I definitely want to highlight this part of JonasH comment

> 3. this probably do not benefit much from parallelization since there is nothing compute heavy inside the loop

your code inside the `Parallel.For` is basically nothing in terms of CPU heavy duty that needs to parallised

Comment: It seems that I am not better off using parallel for .I'm trying to see other ways to improve read loop speed

Comment: @莊秉翰 - did you use a diagnostic tool to see the bottle neck? eg. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/beginners-guide-to-performance-profiling?view=vs-2022